# Stop users from deleting brand new questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, answers

TL;DR It's frustrating when a problem being worked on evaporates before I can hit the submit button.

---

It is **very** frustrating for me to find a question that I feel I can give a good answer to, only to have it deleted just as I'm about to submit my response.

Usually, this is because the questions are asked by first-time posters who don't really get that it's bad etiquette to self delete it, e.g. when it gets a downvote.

I think if the site imposed a ***twenty-four hour*** grace period, it'd help. This way newbies have the chance to think about their post. Hopefully, when they have the inevitable epiphany that leads them to delete their post, they instead update their post with their own answer or select one of the submitted ones. This is really common as I've seen posts from 2011 with correct answers submitted but have never been selected as "the" answer.

Comment: If you'll self delete this now, it would be a big irony. (Please, don't do it, even if this will get some downvotes. Duplicates are useful in their own way)

Comment: Sorry if my edit appears to be "aggressive", but it's for your own good, i.e. in the original version this is not a proper feature request here on Meta. (Context is not needed, asking for two requests in one question isn't good, etc.)

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Also...wow, 6 years ago and they don't seem to have made the suggested change.

Comment: Yes, "wow" is typical response. No worry, you'll get used to it if staying here long enough. :)

Comment: For the record: this *sounds* tempting, but I think it is the wrong approach. You are coming from the "answerer" perspective, who wrote something, and bang, time wasted. I have no idea how often that happens, but guessing from my own experience (and hey, I have a bit of experience on SO): not too often. I think I wrote like 3000+ answers on SO, and maybe 3, 5 times the answer came in after the question got deleted. Now ask yourself: how likely is it that a newbie puts up a bad question, realises that, and drops it himself .My guess: it is better that newbies can delete their questions!

Comment: @KuboMD: Hint: [posting something](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52) [on Twitter](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/what-caused-this-site-to-be-excluded-from-hot-network-questions/3343#3343) is more effective.